# Append string to column value in stored procedure - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to append a string to one of the column values in my stored procedure.

Here's my syntax

```
DECLARE @Newstring VARCHAR(MAX) = 'sample';
....

IF cond1
BEGIN
    SET @query = 'select 
                      e.id, c.address,
                      case when a.lastname is null then a.firstname
                           else a.lastname + ' + @Newstring + '
                      end name,
                      .........'
```

I get an error

> Invalid column name 'sample'

If I execute it as a query, the following concatenation works

```
select 
    e.id, c.address,
    case 
       when a.lastname is null then a.firstname
       else a.lastname + 'sample'
   end name,
```

but I can't use the same syntax in the stored procedure, or cannot use the declared variable. I didn't find any solutions online either.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Invalid column name 'sample'

You query will generate like below. As sample is not a column name, it will throw above error.

```
select 
    e.id, c.address,
    case 
       when a.lastname is null then a.firstname
       else a.lastname + sample
   end name
```

modify your query to include quotes around the parameter

```
set @query = '
           select e.id, c.address,
                  case when a.lastname is null then a.firstname
                       else a.lastname + ''' + @Newstring + '''
                  end name'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give it a datatype... like `varchar`. Change it to:

```
Declare @Newstring varchar(64) = 'sample';
```

And make sure 64 is large enough to hold what ever you are passing into it. If not, use something larger. Also, you may need `NVARCHAR` if you are going to pass in unicode.

Also you are missing a ending quote to the dynamic string, and an `END` to the `BEGIN` and need to add in quote marks to make the value a literal.

```
Declare @Newstring varchar(20) = 'sample'
declare @query varchar(max)
IF 1=1
    BEGIN
      set @query = '
           select e.id, c.address,
                  case when a.lastname is null then a.firstname
                       else a.lastname + ''' + @Newstring + '''  --added quotes to make the string a literal during execution
                  end name' ---quote added here

     END   --added END here


print @query
```

Comment: sorry I missed that in my original post , but I mentioned the datatype and still  the same error. I have edited my post

Comment: had that ending quote too - just ended that in my post with ... . But yes had the ending quote in my sp

Comment: You'd be better off parametrising this too. SQL Injection is not your friend.